# Winterbash overall leaderboard hides hats

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

I noticed a strange behavior of the Winterbash 2013 leaderboard. It seems to hide hats:

[image]
[Link to the displayed page (16.12.2013, 12:03 UTC)](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=9)

Refreshing the page did not solve the problem - and as the number of hats is being displayed correctly I do not think that caching has anything to do with this...

People having earned the same hat multiple times also is not the cause of this behaviour. User jonsca for example has earned five different hats as of now:

[image]

Comment: check this http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=1 I think no space to show all 16 hats for #1, probably some logic I think so

Comment: Yeah well, if there are sixteen hats, there's not enough space to display them all. But as five hats fit quite well into one row (see user "boo" on my screenshot) I don't think that this is the issue here...

Comment: I'm sure this not a bug because if you scroll down the link I provided, each users counts are not matching with the display. some logic though!!!

Comment: Maybe overly aggressive server side cache, caching the hats themselves but not the counter? Let's see in an hour or so. :)

Comment: @Bala When I scroll down the link you provided I see that every single person has six hats displayed, which seems to be the maximum number of hats that can be displayed in a row. As long as a user has more than six hats everything seems to be rendered fine. Once that number has been reached however sometimes hats are missing - as you can [see here](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=7), too.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "overly aggressive" - I just imagine a little monster sitting inside the Stack Exchange servers wearing a huge pile of hats ;)

Comment: Looks like aggressive caching as mentioned by Sha, I think it will render correctly once the cache cleared, anyway as far now it looks strange.

Comment: @Bala nope, no monster for us after all... just small bug. <sad>

Comment: I'm collecting royalties for the use of my image and likeness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was only showing hats from the particular site the user's name is linked to (which is the site where they earned the most hats). Fixed now.

Comment: Still not perfect: http://i.stack.imgur.com/x9uF7.png (seen now)

Comment: Also, might I ask how the hats are ordered? Is this by the time they were given?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Now it should all be fixed (you may sometimes see inconsistencies through caching, but I'm not worried about that too much). They are ordered by rareness, which was the problem here, since they were ordered by the rareness on the same site that I speak of in my answer (where a particular hat may never have been awarded). They're now ordered by network-wide rareness.

Comment: Cool, is there any "rareness points" list available?

Comment: No, but you can mostly deduct it from the leaderboards.