# The hanukiah that was not really there aka zombie L'chaim

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

While browsing the [network leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network), I noticed this:

> [image]

It was not [this bug resurfacing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211810/152859) as it's the opposite: more hats than the count.

I went ahead to the [user profile](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/452/komorra), and he indeed got only one single [Old Hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/old-hat).

There is no trace for [L'chaim](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/lchaim) and it must come from *somewhere* so my first assumption was that the user posted on December 5 and during winterbash that post was deleted. But this means hats are now revoked, [which won't be very popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159216/152859).

So, what does the hanukiah doing there and what happened to it?

P.S.

While searching for the user to see if it maybe sorted itself out while I was typing I found this even weirder case: (and komorra is now gone)

> [image]

For those looking to reproduce, just browse the pages starting at [page 960](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=960) or so.

**Note**: this happens only for the Network Wide leaderboard, per-site leaderboards look fine.

Comment: Looks like hat number is cached ;)

Comment: @Mołot nope, I fear no cache this time. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both data points are sort of correct, but the number is "more correct". On sites that are hatless by default, you don't count as owning a hat until you have opted in. komorra, for example, will receive the L'chaim on Stack Overflow as soon as he or she opts in (a.k.a. "I like hats"). The network-wide leaderboard was counting and ordering correctly by ignoring those not-yet-earned hats, but incorrectly displayed them next to the user.

Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Cheers, this indeed makes lots of sense.